# Is it possible to know the number of users connected by looking haproxy stats?

Tags: haproxy

When I look the stats page ogf my haproxy, I wonder if the term "session" represents the number of different users who are connected to my haproxy.

Comment: up up up up up up up

Answer (score 0):

Session shows number of sessions. Two sessions opened from the same ip address will be shown as two sessions. I don't know a better solution for you than to use socat and "show sess" command. https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/management.html#9.3-show%20sess
then group and count sessions with unique src address.